# C# unmanaged dll exporting (how it works)

Tags: c#, export, hook, unmanaged, managed

I have found libraries that would export *managed* code as *unmanaged* so you can use it by *unmanaged* languages like C/C++. But I did not find anything that would explain how it's done (which is what I'm more interested in)

I'm looking for information, tutorials, articles, code sources or anything that could help me to understand how this works

On a side note, if you found some hooks/detours resources in your bookmarks I would love to read them too :)

Thanks in advance and have a wonderful day.

Comment: There is this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports, documentation https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

Comment: that was my very first words, i found that library, read all about it and still got me no where, i want to fully understand it to the point that i can write my own

Comment: You actually never said **which** library you found!

Comment: @user Black magic. And I'm not kidding. I wouldn't be astonished if there are fairies inside...

Comment: it doesn't matter cause i never said that i need a library that i would just plug and play with :\

Comment: But note that UnmanagedExports is probably the work of a *very very very* experienced programmer... It touches *at least* four "branches" of .NET programming: creating a nuget package that adds a task to a csproj, creating a task for a csproj, using Mono.Cecil, IL Assembler. Remember that you can install it and look at it with ILSpy... it is licensed under the MIT license, so it is probably ok... There doesn't seem to be its source code around.

Answer (score 9):

I'll post an answer, collecting the comments I wrote.

The most famous library for doing it is (as today) the [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports). Its page is https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports . Sadly there is no source code available, but it is licensed under the MIT license, so it is probably ok to use IlSpy to take a look at it.

There are a few references about how it is done.

There are at least two articles on Codeproject: [How to Automate Exporting .NET Function to Unmanaged Programs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16310/How-to-Automate-Exporting-NET-Function-to-Unmanage) that seems to be for .NET 2.0 and [Unmanaged code can wrap managed methods](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8124/Unmanaged-code-can-wrap-managed-methods) that sadly is about .NET 1.1.

There is some reference in the book [Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler](https://goo.gl/GIxgOU) around page 384.

You can surely do another thing: observe what `UnmanagedExports` do: `UnmanagedExports` in the end is "composed" of two parts: an assembly `RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.dll` containing a "stupid" attribute `DllExportAttribute` plus two assemblies (that on my computer the nuget installs in the *packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.6\tools* folder): `RGiesecke.DllExport.dll` and `RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.dll`. The nuget installer of `UnmanagedExports` adds some lines to the csproj, like:

```
<Import Project="packages/UnmanagedExports.1.2.6/tools/RGiesecke.DllExport.targets" Condition="Exists('packages/UnmanagedExports.1.2.6/tools/RGiesecke.DllExport.targets')" />
```

that cause the execution of the class `RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask` contained in the assembly `RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.dll`. <strike>This class, using `Mono.Cecil`, rewrites the assembly doing some code reweaving.</strike>  This program simply calls `ildasm` to generate the il code source, modifies the il code source and then uses `ilasm` to generate back the "original" .dll/.exe . So simply put, generate two assemblies, one with the `<Import />` and another with the `<Import />` commented out, then do a

```
ildasm yourdll.dll /out=source.il
```

of both files and compare it with your favourite file comparer.

Another interesting link is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8648ff5e-c599-42e4-b873-6b91205a5c93/has-anything-been-added-to-net-40-to-support-reverse-pinvoke-scenarios?forum=clr). There are some comments to how to make it work on x64.

<strike>If I had to build something similar, I would probably try to integrate it to [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody). In this way I would have the whole post-build Task for free (because it is done by Fody)</strike>

Can't be done with `Mono.Cecil`... `Mono.Cecil` can't write mixed-mode assemblies (that are needed to export symbols). You have to use the same "trick" used by UnmanagedExports (and by the various other examples)... Generate the IL file, modify it (it is a text file in a fixed format... quite easy to modify), re-generate the .dll/.exe .

Comment: IKVM.Reflection can do it. http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=aeaa0190-2b32-45e6-a249-3c3cf126372b

Comment: @user423430 Yep :-)

Comment: There is a followup / fork available now, which is open source: https://github.com/3F/DllExport/

Answer (score 6):

Here is the source code of unmanaged exports maintained on github:

https://github.com/3F/DllExport

Unmanaged exports has to be doing essentially what c++/cli compiler has to do for reverse pinvoke.